# Changed php-interbase default transaction behaviour

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I have some PHP CLI scripts that run for a long time (24 hours plus) and although they do regular 'commit's I had some problems with orphaned transactions - possibly caused by scripts crashing out.

My solution was to create the transaction as follows - it was a year ago that I researched this and can't quite remember the precise reasons for these settings but it seemed to solve some problems with the database.

$dbh = ibase_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$trans = ibase_trans(IBASE_WRITE+IBASE_COMMITTED+IBASE_REC_VERSION+IBASE_WAIT,$dbh);

Have now upgraded to php 5.3.5 and found that the ibase_trans line causes a segmentation fault. On the php ibase_trans page there is a note:

"The behaviour of this function has been changed in PHP 5.0.0. The first call to ibase_trans() will not return the default transaction of a connection."

So my question is whether I can set the transaction arguments for the default transaction... Secondary question, whether I am entirely missing the point in trying to do this anyway!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not work with default transaction.

Define your transaction as folows:

```
$T = ibase_trans($params, $database);
```

After run your query:

```
 ibase_query($T, $SQL, $Params)
```

or you may use ibase_prepare & ibase_execute.

After it, call

```
ibase_commit_ret($T); // this mentain transaction active
```

or

```
ibase_commit($T) // this commit work close transaction
```